# how to move selected value of drop down list to first position using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

here is my code and i want to display the selected value at first position in the drop down list.

Organization

```
  <div class="ui selection dropdown" > 
    <input type="hidden"
           name="organization"
           ng-model="accountDetails.organization">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>


    <div class="text" 
         ng-class="{ 'default':(!accountDetails.organization)  }">None

    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item"
           ng-repeat="(shortName, organization) in organizations"
           ng-click="accountDetails.organization"
           data-value="{{ organizationName(shortName)}}"
           data-text="{{ organizationName(shortName) }}">
           {{ organization}} 
      </div>      
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an array, instead of iterating over the properties of an object, which have no intrinsic order.

Once you have this array of organizations, make sure the one you want in first position is the first element of the array, and use

```
<div class="item"
       ng-repeat="org in organizations"
       ng-click="selectOrganization(org)"
       data-value="{{ organizationName(org.shortName)}}"
       data-text="{{ organizationName(org.shortName) }}">
       {{ org.organization}} 
</div>
```

That said, even if it would definitely be a good idea to use an array rather than an object, I would avoir reordering elements of the menu each time the user selects one. That will confuse the users, and look really strange.

Comment: thanks for your reply i tried using your solution but drop down list itself is not coming.

Comment: We can't find a bug without seeing the code. Edit your question and post all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Let ng-repeat over an Array as already said and write a filter, that doesn't really filter but rather re-arrange your array. HTML like already posted including the filter:

```
<div class="item"
       ng-repeat="org in organizations | customFilter: accountDetails.organization"
       ng-click="selectOrganization(org)"
       data-value="{{ organizationName(org.shortName)}}"
       data-text="{{ organizationName(org.shortName) }}">
       {{ org.organization}} 
</div>
```

and the filter:

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {

  return function(input, organization) {

  var out = [];

  angular.forEach(input, function(organization) {
    if (organization === input) {
        out.unshift(input);
    }else{
        out.push(input);
    } 
  })

return out;
}});
```

Didn't test it and it might not work without editing though.

Comment: Well, we can't assume your angularJS Code, neither can we assume the structure of your objects. It wont work until you adjust the "object" you pass through the filter (you obviously don't type in an object but a string to the input). So, you need to edit it e.g. by comparing organization (as string) with input.shortName